# Tkinter Information from Get Name into a List

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am currently writing a code, that uses a GUI made by Tkinter.  My problem is that I want to create a script that:
A. Opens a Window (which I did, and it loops), and if the window could stay open and shift to a blank version of itself.
B: Take all the names in Get Name and put them into a list, to be chugged into a dataframe for processing. 
I wrote significant code.

This is my attempt

```
from tkinter import *
class Name:
    def __init__(self):
        window = Tk()
        window.title('Names to be processed please: ')
        frame1 = Frame(window)
        frame1.pack()
        label = Label(frame1, text = "Enter a name: ")
        self.name = StringVar()
        self.v1 = IntVar()
        self.v2 = IntVar()
        entryname = Entry(frame1, text = self.name)
        btGetName = Button(frame1, text = 'Get Name', command = self.processButton)
        btFinished = Checkbutton(frame1, text = 'Finished',
                                 variable = self.v1, command = self.finishedButton)
        btNotFinished = Checkbutton(frame1, text = 'Not Finished',
                                 variable = self.v2, command = self.unfinishedButton)
        label.grid(row = 1, column = 2)
        btGetName.grid(row = 1, column = 3)
        btFinished.grid(row = 2, column = 2)
        btNotFinished.grid(row = 2, column = 3)
        text = Text(window)
        text.pack()
        window.mainloop()
    def processButton(self):
        name = self.name.get()
        return name
    def finishedButton(self):
        a = self.v1.get()
        return a
    def unfinishedButton(self):
        b = (1 if self.v2.get() == 1 else 0)
        return b
obj = Name()
name = []
while obj.finishedButton() != 1:
    Name()
    for i in obj.processButton():
        name.append(i)
print(name)
```

The common error is that I get a blank list. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple mistake in your code. You want to make sure you're actually including entryname in your layout, which I don't see in your code. I added entryname to the bottom of your layout by including the line `entryname.grid(row = 3, column = 1)` after the rest of your grid lines.

Adding this line should fix your problem. I was then able to print out `self.name.get()` in the function `processButton` just fine.

**Update**: If you want to save the names the user has entered into a list, you can do so in the function `processButton`. See the code below on how to do this. From here, you can create a dataframe from this list.

```py
def processButton(self):
        name_list = []
        name = self.name.get()
        name_list.append(name)
        print('Names list consists of: ', name_list)
        return name_list
```

Comment: I still can't get it to print out.

Comment: Do you have a print function in ```processButton```? I don't see one in your original code. Just try ```print(name)```.

Comment: Kelsey if I want to save the names I insert and then use them in a dataframe?

Comment: @JoseSerra I've updated my code to save these names to a list. If this now works for you, please mark this answer as accepted.